# C++/CX concurrency::create_task with DataReader LoadAsync function cause: 'The operation identifier is not valid.'

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, uwp, c++-cx, hololens

I am developing a TCP client module for Hololens 1st gen with native C++/CX.

I create a packet class which contains 1 x (uint32_t) + 7 x (float)
The server is implemented in the synchronized manner, which streams the packets to the client (Hololens) every frame.

Receiver.h

```
namespace HoloNet {
    public ref class holoATCFrameReceiver sealed
    {
    public:
        holoATCFrameReceiver(
            _In_ Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocket^ streamSocket);

        Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<TrackerFrame^>^ ReceiveAsync();


    private:
        Concurrency::task<TrackerFrame^> ReceiveTrackerFrameAsync();


    private:
        Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocket^ _streamSocket;


        Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader^      _reader;
        bool                                        _readInProgress;

    };
}
```

and Receiver.cpp

```
namespace HoloNet {
    holoATCFrameReceiver::holoATCFrameReceiver(
        Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocket ^ streamSocket)
        : _streamSocket(streamSocket)
    {
        _readInProgress = false;

        // reader
        _reader = ref new Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader(
            _streamSocket->InputStream);

        _reader->UnicodeEncoding =
            Windows::Storage::Streams::UnicodeEncoding::Utf8;

        _reader->ByteOrder =
            Windows::Storage::Streams::ByteOrder::LittleEndian;
    }

    Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<TrackerFrame^>^ holoATCFrameReceiver::ReceiveAsync()
    {
        return concurrency::create_async(
            [this]()
            {
                return ReceiveTrackerFrameAsync();
            });
    }

    Concurrency::task<TrackerFrame^> 
        holoATCFrameReceiver::ReceiveTrackerFrameAsync()
    {
        return concurrency::create_task(
            _reader->LoadAsync(TrackerFrame::TrackerFrameLength)
        ).then([this](Concurrency::task<unsigned int> headerBytesLoadedTaskResult)
        {
            headerBytesLoadedTaskResult.wait();
            const size_t frameBytesLoaded = headerBytesLoadedTaskResult.get();

            if (TrackerFrame::TrackerFrameLength != frameBytesLoaded)
            {
                throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
            }


            _readInProgress = true;

            TrackerFrame^ header;

            TrackerFrame::Read(
                _reader,
                &header);

            dbg::trace(
                L"SensorFrameReceiver::ReceiveAsync: sensor %i: t( %f, %f %f ), q( %f, %f, %f, %f)",
                header->sensorID,
                header->x,
                header->y,
                header->z,
                header->qw,
                header->qx,
                header->qy,
                header->qz);

            _readInProgress = false;

            return header;
        });
    }

}
```

The error throws at *** _reader->LoadAsync(TrackerFrame::TrackerFrameLength) ***

[image]

The receiver is called in the client class like below:

```
    void holoTcpATCClient::OnReceiveATCframe(TrackerFrame^& header) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_socketMutex);
        // check read in process
        if (_readInProcess)
        {
            return;
        }

        _readInProcess = true;
        concurrency::create_task(
            _receiver->ReceiveAsync()).then(
                [&](concurrency::task<TrackerFrame^> sensorFrameTask)
        {
            sensorFrameTask.wait();
            TrackerFrame^ sensorFrame = sensorFrameTask.get()
            header =  sensorFrame;
        });
        _readInProcess = false;
    }
```

***_receiver->ReceiveAsync()*** is the begining of the error.

I wonder whether there is a way to pretend this happens by doing some modification on LoadAsync() of DataReader for StreamSocket under concurrency:: create_task?
Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Is your socket connected correctly and whether the TrackerFrame::TrackerFrameLength parameter passed to _reader->LoadAsync() method is correct? And there is an related [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket), you can refer to it to check your code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Faywang-MSFT, I am double-checking that part and find the parameter is correct. Here is the way I compute TrackerFrame::TrackerFrameLength:    ` static property uint32_t TrackerFrameLength
  {
   uint32_t get()
   {
    return (sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(float) * 7);
   }
  }`

Comment: Is it possible the receiver reads too fast that leads to this error, which can add some detection before _reader->LoadAsync()?

Comment: When I used the officail sample, it worked well. So can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?